# A ghost is propagating an Apache redirect

Tags: apache, windows

I have a httpd.conf file with some redirects like this:

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted

    Redirect /just-text https://other.site.tld/directory?query
</Directory>
```

They were working just fine, then I changed them to point at a different target. I restarted Apache (`httpd -k restart` as administrator) but the redirects still pointed at the old target. I restarted the server itself and the same thing happened -- the old targets were somehow still being followed, despite not appearing anywhere in the file.

I was able to replicate this <s>in a new browser</s> from another machine that had never seen the website before, so it's not a browser cache issue (could be a server cache issue of course, though `cache_module` isn't loaded). Any ideas?

I'm running Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) on Windows Server 2012R2.

Comment: Have you cleared your DNS from the operating system? browser? and router? since redirects are often cached locally, not just on the web server. Try an online CURL rather than testing the redirect using your computer.

Comment: @SimonHayter No dice. I even tried it from another machine at another location (not sharing network infrastructure).

Comment: Like Simon, I recommend testing with [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) on the command line.   It removes a lot of headaches associated  with browser cache.    I'd trust it even over finding another machine.

Comment: This could also be caused by a caching proxy or content delivery network (CDN).   If you have a proxy or CDN, it also needs to be restarted or cache flushed.  You can bypass a CDN using `curl https:// DOMAIN.TLD --resolve "DOMAIN.TLD:443:IP_ADDRESS"` to specify the the direct IP address for your upstream server. [source](https://serverfault.com/questions/443949/how-to-test-a-https-url-with-a-given-ip-address)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That's... interesting. I'm not running a CDN or a proxy server, but `curl` was able to get the right page.

Comment: @Charles then you have internal caching on your machine. Windows can cache DNS redirects, browsers can cache redirects and even some routers do. if using Windows close all browsers, then do a ipconfig /flushdns followed by rebooting the router. Then try to go to the website address.